# How can I establish a conda env based on python source alone?

Tags: python, conda

I have cloned a git repo to do some work. It came with an environment.yml.
However it fails to install on my win10 anaconda3. The YML file had entires like: - numpy=1.16.6=py27hbc911f0_0

I was advised to remove second = and numerals to right of it.
That sort of worked but there were several conflicts.

I distrust this env as I cannot see the source referencing all 124 modules that are in the YML. I want to make a cut down env based purely on the existing source.

How do I discover all the correct library/modules based on the source without lots of trial and error runs?

Comment: I dont think there is any available tool for this, just search for import in your project folder and add the packages to your environment file.

Comment: thank you for the reply. yes that is where i am at. There are only 13 unique imports so it should be straightforward. I had hoped there might be a tool to scan the python.

Comment: [The `modulefinder` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html) ships with Python. However, translating from modules to Conda package names isn't always literal.

Comment: module finder sounds promising, but I would have to provide every filename, right?

Comment: Yes, check all the files. But that shouldn't too hard to script out (e.g., use `glob` to match `.py` files in the project).